# Graph SDK OAUTH ADAL client credentials for reuse? later

Tags: wpf, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, adal, onedrive

So we have an application that allows you to create a xml file that runs the app again at a later stage (which may or may not have a user in attendance). Files are stored on the user cloud drive platform of choice. So the process is

**Workflow** 1

Authenticate to cloud with User 1 details/input
Select files to Download and use
Save and encrypt file metadata and Refresh token to xml file. (app workflow 1)

**Workflow 2** ( can be repeated multiple thousands of times)
Send xml file to another pc with User 2. (either by email or remotely through a console
that pc then runs under user 2

start app
App authenticates automatically using refresh token saved in xml file with no user input (as there is a very high chance of the user who created workflow 1 not being in the same city as where workflow 2 is running
Downloads files
applies files (app workflow 2)
**PROBLEM**
all other platforms we cater for (Dropbox and google and onedrive) gives us access to the refresh token and allow us to authenticate with it again , however the onedrive for business (graph sdks) give us a Token cache which is session based?

**Questions**

So I need to know how I can get the refresh token from the Token Cache so we can reuse it at a later stage. (yes I'm aware that it will expire after 6 months which is acceptable) .

When i have the refresh token how do initiate a call to refresh the token

Further note - I have managed to handle all platforms before Within silverlight (where the sdks are not supported) through directly calling the rest api calls but we are converting our solution to WPF and would want to use the sdks

thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could provide code with your question (what you have tried so far). I really don't get a grasp of what you have tried before asking the question.

Comment: My answer to in another question may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001358/1653521

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so the answer is taking the tokencache from the PublicIdentityApp and serializing as below.

```
   var tokenCache = _app.UserTokenCache;
   var tokenBytes = tokenCache.Serialize();
   var tokenString = Convert.ToBase64String(tokenBytes);
```

And deserializing it later.

```
_app = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication(ClientID);
var array = Convert.FromBase64String(bytestring);
_app.UserTokenCache.Deserialize(array);
authHelper = new AuthenticationHelper(_app);
var authorise = await authHelper.GetTokenForUserAsync()
```

Comment: Barry, your answer isn't helping at all. You didn't provide code in your question and the code in your answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you were developing [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) when you mentioned **graph sdks**.

AFAIK, this library does not include any default authentication implementations. Instead, the user will want to authenticate with the library of their choice, or against the OAuth endpoint directly, and built-in DelegateAuthenticationProvider class to authenticate each request.

And if you were authenticating Azure AD with [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/), you can use the [default token cache](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/ADAL.Common/TokenCache.cs) which use memory to store the cache or you can implement the token cache based on your requirement.

> So I need to know how I can get the refresh token from the Token Cache so we can reuse it at a later stage. (yes I'm aware that it will expire after 6 months which is acceptable) .

When you using the ADAL library, there is no need to get the refresh token manually, it will handle for us to renew the access token if the refresh token is existed.

> When i have the refresh token how do initiate a call to refresh the token

If you want to perform the request yourself to refresh the access token, you can refer the request below, and more detail you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,So can I  just serialize the token cache and set it again later? where an automated process can read it from file and set it and then authenticate? without the original user present ? thats the main issue there is 99% chance that the original person logging in will not be there and even if they are , they will want it to automatically authenticate them

Comment: Also i am using the delegate authentication provider and i have checked through fiddler  .. the token cache never receives a refresh token

Comment: Fei, I don't think you're answering the question. You don't provide a way to get the token back and etc. Instead you point that Azure AD can do that while OP is asking how to achieve that using Microsoft.Graph API.