# Storing and retrieving access token when using Client Credential Flow in .Net

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I m using a client credential flow to access the API. I am getting the access token each time client make a call to Web API which seem to me may not be good but not sure why. I looked through web I am getting mix answer, some say Client Credential flow doesn't return refresh token some say possible but it is not clear how. I looked at the project where it seem to store the token in the cache but doesn't show how it can be use when needing to get the access token.

Even if Client Credential flow doesn't support or send refresh token. I am searching for a way to store the access token and use it until is is not expired and get a new one when it is expire. This is where I am looking for support.

Beside that I do have relevant question.

1. Should I just get the access token each time? what is the downfall of it?
2. Should I include a Test method is Web Api to validate if the token is expired and return "Unauthorize" response based on that response I get the new token?   With this approach, I will calling the API each time I need to access the API for actual purpose. So wouldn't I just get the access token from the Authorization server (Microsoft Identity platform).

Comment: Here's an [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/blob/master/1-Call-MSGraph/daemon-console/Program.cs) for client-credential flow, you may refer to it.

Comment: thanks , I took a look at that project it uses only single method to call the api. But it doesn't really show the use of the cache. It jsut have an additional method   app.AddInMemoryTokenCache();.  Do you think this method would take care of getting the token from the cache.  In order to do what I have to do.  Should I continue to call to get the token but behind the scene I will get the token from the cache if it is still valid?

Comment: [Another sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi) for calling custom api. And per my understanding, whether to store the token or not is based on your own requirement, if you want to do it, then you need to generate token -> store token -> write re-generate token method -> write api response handler to check if need to generate new token and send request again. In your api, you need to write a intercepter to validate the token and write custom response when token  is expired. I usually create new token each time I need tocall api

Comment: If you generate new token each time. Then why there is emphasis on the refreshing the token or getting the token from the cache.  For me it is easy approach. Never need to worry about if token is expire or refreshing it.

Comment: token stored in cookie and refresh token are used for delegate permission api, which means you have a website to let users signed in, and this kind of authentication will generate access token alone with the refresh token. Access token will expire after 1h by default, and if you don't want your users to sign in again, then refresh token can be used here. But this structure is not suitable for client credential flow, this flow will not offer you a refresh token, so storing an access token here makes no sense because you can't refresh it.

Comment: I had a explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270742/15581227)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure we are in the same situation, but I have followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3

I struggled to find a way to save user authentication tokens, so the users don't have to authenticate every time my app starts.

Then I found out that `DeviceCodeCredentialOptions` has `TokenCachePersistenceOptions`. The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/azure.identity.devicecodecredentialoptions.tokencachepersistenceoptions?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-devicecodecredentialoptions-tokencachepersistenceoptions) clearly says:

`Specifies the TokenCachePersistenceOptions to be used by the credential. If not options are specified, the token cache will not be persisted to disk.`

There is an example in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/azure.identity.tokencachepersistenceoptions?view=azure-dotnet) for using `TokenCachePersistenceOptions`. However, if you using Microsoft Graph, you need to tweak the code a little bit. Here is the code that works for me:

```cs
public static readonly string[] GraphUserScopes = new[]
{
    "user.read",
    "mail.read",
    "mail.send",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
};

public static async Task SampleRunAsync()
{
    var deviceCodeCredentialOptions = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions()
    {
        ClientId = ApplicationClientId,
        TenantId = DirectoryTenantId,
        DeviceCodeCallback = (info, cancle) =>
        {
            // Display the device code message to
            // the user. This tells them
            // where to go to sign in and provides the
            // code to use.
            Console.WriteLine(info.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions() {Name = TokenName}
    };
    DeviceCodeCredential deviceCodeCredential;
    if (File.Exists(TokenFp))
    {
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(TokenFp, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        deviceCodeCredentialOptions.AuthenticationRecord = await AuthenticationRecord.DeserializeAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(Program.DebugMode);
        deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(deviceCodeCredentialOptions);
    }
    else
    {
        deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(deviceCodeCredentialOptions);
        var authenticationRecord = await deviceCodeCredential.AuthenticateAsync(new TokenRequestContext(GraphUserScopes)).ConfigureAwait(Program.DebugMode);
        //
        using var fileStream1 = new FileStream(TokenFp, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        await authenticationRecord.SerializeAsync(fileStream1).ConfigureAwait(Program.DebugMode);

    }

    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, GraphUserScopes);

    var user = await graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync((config) =>
    {
        // Only request specific properties
        config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] {"displayName", "mail", "userPrincipalName"};
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {user?.DisplayName}!");
    // For Work/school accounts, email is in Mail property
    // Personal accounts, email is in UserPrincipalName
    Console.WriteLine($"Email: {user?.Mail ?? user?.UserPrincipalName ?? ""}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these resources:

- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnet

One possible solution is to implement internally your own solution:

1. Get the Token.
2. A Dictionary is going to hold the (API type) as a key and the corresponding token as its value.
3. Next call check if the token exists in your Dic(TryGetValu(ket, out param)).
4. Check "ExpiresOn" on the AuthenticationResult (the Token) and compare its time for validation.

Remember to maintain your Dic by Updating or adding new tokens.